# Same code base, different APKs, differents ressources files and different webservices urls

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk

Lets imagine the following case:
I'm building an application for cars, lets say VW. Now Skoda (belongs to the same group) wants the very same application but with different ressources files, and some checks need to be made into the code like. If VW, call this webservice, else if Skoda, call this other one.

I can't really answer to this question: "Is it the same application?" 
Yes from the code point of view but no from the play store point of view...

How can I manage to have the same code base but with two different packages name?

I think I am in the good track reading this http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants but if you have any tricks, advice or help to share I would be glad to hear :)
I know this question has been asked, but I'm looking for a solution with gradle & Android Studio.

Tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id of the application used by googles's play store is defined in the Build.gradle file : 
like

```
productFlavors {
        vw {
            applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.vw"
        }
        skoda {
            applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.skoda"
        }
```

The ressources folder simply needs to be created under the new flavor's auto generated folder. see http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidStudioTooling/article.html#androidstudio_creatingresourcefolder for more info

Answer (score 2):

Hello you can use product flavor to define the package name for each new application as @stoke said

`productFlavors {
        app1 {
            applicationId  "com.example.package.app1"
            buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", "\"https://www.myapi.com/apiv1/\""
        }
        app2 {
            applicationId "com.example.package.app2"
            buildConfigField "String", "API_URL","\"https://www.myapi.com/apiv2/\""
       }
}`

For defining different endpoints or url in your builds you can define build variable to use in your code.

Then you can access them like BuildConfig.API_URL in your java code.

For different resources for diferent flavors you need to define 2 directories that match the new flavors names.

Check [this](http://tulipemoutarde.be/2013/10/06/gradle-build-variants-for-your-android-project.html) for file sctructure and resources.

Comment: I'll add that if you have a lot of Strings or other resources you want to switch by flavor, you can create {flavor_name}/res/... files instead of defining them all in the build.gradle file

Comment: @RobertNekic I said "For different resources for diferent flavors you need to define 2 directories that match the new flavors names" and in the url is the deeper explanation about structure of project where it has different icon and string for each flavor

Comment: @RobertNekic I just use buildConfigFields to define the restApi Url and google api keys, but is just that feels right having right there in the build for me.